# Javascript Unexpected reserved word error

Tags: javascript

I am playing with a client side router code from https://github.com/dcode-youtube/single-page-app-vanilla-js repo. I try to change this code in a way that i can reuse, because in the original code he hardcoded the routes in the router function.

I know(i think i know) the main reason why i get the unexpected reserved word error, i just dont know how to solve it.

Router.js

```
export default class trdsRouter{

    constructor(routes){

        this.routes = routes;
        window.addEventListener("popstate", this.run);

        document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
            if (e.target.matches("[trds-router-link]")) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.navigateTo(e.target.href);
            }
        });
 
    }

    run = () => {

        const potentialMatches = this.routes.map(route => {
            return {
                route: route,
                result: location.pathname.match(pathToRegex(route.path))
            };
        });

        let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.result !== null);

        if (!match) {
            match = {
                route: this.routes[0],
                result: [location.pathname]
            }
        }

        // THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
        const view = new match.route.view(getParams(match));

        document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();

    }

    navigateTo = url => {
        history.pushState(null, null, url);
        this.run();
    }

}

const pathToRegex = path => new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/:\w+/g, "(.+)") + "$");

const getParams = match => {
    const values = match.result.slice(1);
    const keys = Array.from(match.route.path.matchAll(/:(\w+)/g)).map(result => result[1]);

    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => {
        return [key, values[i]];
    }));
};
```

where i construct the router:

```
import trdsRouter from "./router.js";

import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard.js";
import Posts from "./views/Posts.js";
import PostView from "./views/PostView.js";
import Settings from "./views/Settings.js";

let router = new trdsRouter([
    { path: "/", view: Dashboard },
    { path: "/posts", view: Posts },
    { path: "/posts/:id", view: PostView },
    { path: "/settings", view: Settings }
]);

router.run();
```

And then there is the abstract view class(i extend this class for the dashboard, posts, etc.):

```
export default class {
    constructor(params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    setTitle(title) {
        document.title = title;
    }

    async getHtml() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

So i think the problem is that in the trdsRouter class it does not yet know that a routes view property is a class( but i pass a class to it when i construct the router), thats why it throws error. how would i solve this? thank you.

Comment: The abstract view class that you are exporting doesn't have a name.

Comment: @GenericUser class can be anonymous.

Comment: What is the actual error being thrown and what line does it refer to?

Comment: @yqlim I wasn't even aware the language supported that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. the first code snippet contains a comment line that points out the erroring line. You probably need to scroll down a bit.

Comment: Yes, its commented out and throws an unexpected reserved keyword 'new' error

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry guys, it was a terrible mistake. The problem wasnt the new keyword highlighted in the routers code but the next line with the 'await' keyword. The routers run function wasnt declared as async so it threw the error. Changed the run function to async and it works. Thank you for your comments.